# How do I set the default size of a new window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a WPF application. All the windows I'm using are 1980x1080.

However, whenever I create a new window the default size of it is 300x300.

It is quite annoying to have to change it every time, so I am wondering if there is a way to set the default new window size.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the size you want in the XAML file and export a new template from: `File->Export Template` and choose Item Template.

Then when you want to add a new window, you choose your custom template instead of the default.

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates).